# enforce java interface on an object created by java reflections

Tags: java

- I read a full class name from config file

  - eg: org.a.b.c.DefaultHandler
- This class implements a method called "handler"
- I use java reflection to invoke "handler"

  ```
  Class cls = Class.forName("org.a.b.c.DefaultHandler");
  handlerObj = cls.newInstance();
  method = cls.getMethod("handler", cArg);
  method.invoke(handlerObj, service);
  ```

class looks like:

```
public class DefaultHandler {

    public void handler(String service) throws Exception {
       ...
    }

}
```

I need to make sure any `*Handler Class` implements `"handler"` method. If I do something like

```
public class DefaultHandler implements handlerInterface {
  ...
}
```

Its not of much use as compiler wont help as I use reflection.

So how can I enforce an interface on an instance of a class that is invoked/created by java reflections????

Comment: I don't understand your question. An object created like so `handlerObj = cls.newInstance();` is no different than an object created like `new org.a.b.c.DefaultHandler()` in your example.

Comment: Since reflection is, by nature and definition, a runtime tool, I don't believe you can enforce anything related to the class definition, which is a compile-time requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do anything at compile time to enforce that it's a `handlerInterface`, because reflection is inherently a runtime activity.

The best you can do is to cast it as your interface `handlerInterface`.  If it's not, then a `ClassCastException` will be thrown, which you can handle appropriately.

```
try {
    handlerInterface handler = (handlerInterface) handlerObj;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // Handle appropriately
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either check the method signature; the code (understandably) did not check much: normally one would call `getConstructor().newInstance()` for instance, for the possible exceptions.

If having an interface, do:

```
if (!HandlerInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
    // Error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with generics :

```
Class<handlerInterface> cls = Class.forName("org.a.b.c.DefaultHandler");
handlerInterface handlerObj = cls.newInstance();
```

The last line with throw `ClassCastException` if it does not `implements handlerInterface` which you can handle appropriately.